# for loop inside try catch return without execute next line

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a function for converting xml string to list array. while reaching the last condition,it jumps to the last return of the function.

The code does not execute the return statement after the for loop.and it does not execute any line after the for loop. It just execute the last return statement.

function is shown below

```
public List<List<String>> UpdateOrderDetailsTable(String xml) {
        List<List<String>> ll = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ProductDetails");
            Log.i("1111",Integer.toString(nList.getLength()));
            if (nList.getLength() > 0) {


                // get all order details
                            //i=1 for neglect first tag
                for (int i = 1; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node nNode = nList.item(i);


                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
                            l.add(0, eElement.getElementsByTagName("OrderId").item(0).getTextContent());
                            l.add(1, eElement.getElementsByTagName("ProductId").item(0).getTextContent());
                            l.add(2, eElement.getElementsByTagName("ProductName").item(0).getTextContent());
                            l.add(3, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0).getTextContent());
                            l.add(4, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Quantity").item(0).getTextContent());
                            ll.add(l);

                            Log.i(Integer.toString(i),eElement.getElementsByTagName("OrderId").item(0).getTextContent());

                    }

                }

                return ll;
            }
            Log.i("2222222222222222222","222222222222222222");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("11111", e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

[this is my xml](http://smartcityjobs.in/sample.xml)

Comment: That means an exception was thrown in your `for` loop! Debug your code and find out which line is throwing what exception!

Comment: What do you see in your log?

Comment: is your logcat prints  any exceptions

Comment: @R.J i am on debugging mode.it just jump to last return while it execute last forloop check.

Comment: @BevynQ it just log the log statement inside the for loop log.it does not print outside logs.no errors no exeptions

Comment: @kannan - firstly, your `for` loop is wrong. you need to have `for(int i=0;i<len;i++)`. The reason being, if the size of your list is `1`, it'll enter the for, but will throw an IOOB exception at `Node nNode = nList.item(i);` and will directly go to your catch, the last return!

Comment: @R.J i need to skip the first tag.so i=1.it does not throw any exception.

Comment: @kannan - without any exception, it won't skip those lines. Also, you need to post your logcat, else you won't get the required help!

Comment: when i tried to run it, its showing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: unterminated entity, exception, on the line Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

Comment: @umesh but its fine 4 me

Comment: @kannan: look i am unable to find out where the problem is, but can give you another parser, that can parse this xml data

Answer (score 0):

Use `i=0` operator

```
// get all order details
                for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
}

}
```

Comment: what if there is only one element in nList, then it will be ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: @umesh: if nList contain 1 element then `nList.getLength()` gets `1` not a `0`.`length` is start from 1 and index is start from `0`.

Comment: ok then in the line Node nNode = nList.item(i);, you will try to access element at index 1, that is not available

Comment: i=1 because i want to neglect first node

Comment: if you want to neglect 1st node then use this condition `if(nList.getLength() > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it can be deduced that the only case it will not execute any statement after for loop is that you are getting some EXCETPION. And as per your comments, you are saying you are not seeing any exception in the logs. Then i doubt your logger, for the sake of testing try to put some Sysout statements to make sure that logger is correct. Your log.e() method may not be working properly, just try to put your log.i() in the exception block and see.

Comment: correct, he is getting any Exception, why don't he post logcat output

Comment: i'm sure.i alrdy put a break point inside catch.if i manually put a nullpointer it will catch.so no problem for logger and catch.Then y???

Comment: @umesh the log cat only shows logs inside the for loop.i'm investigate this past 8 hours

Comment: @kannan: please post the xml data also, i'll resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the first item, then change `if (nList.getLength() > 0)` statement to `if (nList.getLength() > 1)`

Also put an `else` statement for `if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)` and put a log output. E.g.:

```
if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add(0, eElement.getElementsByTagName("OrderId").item(0).getTextContent());
    l.add(1, eElement.getElementsByTagName("ProductId").item(0).getTextContent());
    l.add(2, eElement.getElementsByTagName("ProductName").item(0).getTextContent());
    l.add(3, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Model").item(0).getTextContent());
    l.add(4, eElement.getElementsByTagName("Quantity").item(0).getTextContent());
    ll.add(l);
    Log.i(Integer.toString(i), eElement.getElementsByTagName("OrderId").item(0).getTextContent());
} else {
    Log.wtf("1111", "Item " + i + "is not Node.ELEMENT_NODE type");
}
```

It just could be none of your nodes are type `ELEMENT_NODE`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<ProductDetails> parserData(String data) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;
    ArrayList<ProductDetails> productDetailsList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
    ProductDetails productDetails = null;
    data = data.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
    data = data.replaceAll("<BR />", "");

    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(data));

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if ("ProductDetails".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails = new ProductDetails();
                } else if ("OrderId".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails.setOrderId(Integer.parseInt(parser.nextText()));
                } else if ("ProductId".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails.setProductId(Integer.parseInt(parser.nextText()));
                } else if ("ProductName".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails.setProductName(parser.nextText());
                } else if ("Model".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails.setModel(parser.nextText());
                } else if ("Quantity".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetails.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(parser.nextText()));
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if ("ProductDetails".equals(parser.getName())) {
                    productDetailsList.add(productDetails);
                }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return productDetailsList;
}
```